# Rails autosave not saving changes to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autosave

I'm trying to do the following to make changes to both the parent and child association using autosave but with no success.

```
@child = @parent.childs.last
if child's attribute satisfies some condition
  @parent.something = "asd"
  @child.something = params[:something]
end

@parent.save
```

This only saves the change made to the parent. Is there a way to save both changes with only one "save" call?

Comment: Did you set the autosave option on the child? `belongs_to :parent, autosave: true`

Comment: No, do I have to?

Comment: I was not able to find what the default is, but I guess setting this option should do what you want. Documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-autosave

Comment: I think the option is set on the parent. Documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

Comment: You are right, you need to set it on the parent for your case, the option is supported in most association types.

Answer (score 1):

By default only new association records are automatically saved. You need to enable the autosave mechanism by passing an option to the association, see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html.

```
class Parent
  has_many :children, autosave: true
end
```

Note that this only works one way, if you want the parent to be saved, when you save the child, you need the reverse

```
class Child
  belongs_to: parent, autosave: true
end
```

This only works as long as Rails knows you are working on an association. Calling `@parent.childs.last` gives you back a simple instance of the `Child` class. So you need to explicitly save it.

Comment: That's what I've done. has_many :children, autosave:true. But it doesn't save the change made to the child.

Comment: And you are sure, your application executes the `if` block?

Comment: Yes, the change to the parent is saved.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is, when you call `last` on the `childs` it is no longer an `ActiveRecord::Associations` so it is detached from the parent. So either you edit directly the  `ActiveRecord::Associations` or you need to explicitly save the child.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping!